# Keep my algorithmic environment in one piece without using figure environment

Tags: floats, numbering, algorithms

I am working on a paper and I wish to use the `algorithmic` environment. The problem is, if I use the following code:

```
    \begin{algorithmic}[H]
    \label{alg1}
    \FOR{$-M_x<m_x<M_x$}
        \FOR{$-M_y<m_y<M_y$}
            \FOR{$-M_z<m_z<M_z$}
                \FOR{$0\leq q\leq 1$}
                    \FOR{$0\leq j\leq 1$}
                        \FOR{$0\leq k\leq 1$}
                            \STATE $1$
                            \STATE $2$
                            \STATE $3$
                        \ENDFOR
                    \ENDFOR
                \ENDFOR
            \ENDFOR
        \ENDFOR
    \ENDFOR
    \end{algorithmic}
```

The algorithm can start in one column, break, and continue in another column:

[image]

The only way I found to resulve this is by adding a figure environment:

```
   \begin{figure}  
    \begin{algorithmic}[H]
    \caption{Algorithm}\label{alg1}
    \FOR{$-M_x<m_x<M_x$}
        \FOR{$-M_y<m_y<M_y$}
            \FOR{$-M_z<m_z<M_z$}
                \FOR{$0\leq q\leq 1$}
                    \FOR{$0\leq j\leq 1$}
                        \FOR{$0\leq k\leq 1$}
                            \STATE $1$
                            \STATE $2$
                            \STATE $3$
                        \ENDFOR
                    \ENDFOR
                \ENDFOR
            \ENDFOR
        \ENDFOR
    \ENDFOR
    \end{algorithmic}
    \end{figure}
```

The problem is that this colides with my figures numbering. I also tried using `\begin{figure*}` but in this way I cannot referance the algorithm.

Is there a way to keep the algorithm without brakes and avoid messing up the figure numbering?

Comment: `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}<your stuff>\end{minipage}`

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer you an `algorithmic*` environment; the caption has to be specified as an argument.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic,etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{algorithmic*}[1]
 {%
  % remove the rule below
  \par\vspace{-\bigskipamount}
  \appto{\fs@ruled}{\def\@fs@post{}}
  \begin{algorithm}[H]
  \caption{#1}
  \end{algorithm}\nobreak\vspace{-\medskipamount}
  \begin{algorithmic}
 }
 {\end{algorithmic}\par\nobreak\kern2pt\hrule\bigskip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]\lipsum[3][1-3]

\bigskip

\begin{algorithmic*}{Algorithm\label{alg1}}
\FOR{$-M_x<m_x<M_x$}
  \FOR{$-M_y<m_y<M_y$}
    \FOR{$-M_z<m_z<M_z$}
      \FOR{$0\leq q\leq 1$}
        \FOR{$0\leq j\leq 1$}
          \FOR{$0\leq k\leq 1$}
            \STATE $1$
            \STATE $2$
            \STATE $3$
          \ENDFOR
        \ENDFOR
      \ENDFOR
    \ENDFOR
  \ENDFOR
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic*}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add the [`algorithm` package](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) to your preamble - it provides the `algorithm` floating environment and its own associated counters.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algcompatible}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\sloppy\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}
  \FOR{$-M_x < m_x < M_x$}
    \FOR{$-M_y < m_y < M_y$}
      \FOR{$-M_z < m_z < M_z$}
        \FOR{$0 \leq q \leq 1$}
          \FOR{$0 \leq j \leq 1$}
            \FOR{$0 \leq k \leq 1$}
              \STATE $1$
              \STATE $2$
              \STATE $3$
            \ENDFOR
          \ENDFOR
        \ENDFOR
      \ENDFOR
    \ENDFOR
  \ENDFOR
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[3-5]

\end{document}
```